# Load testing of endpoint in Azure ML

Tags: deployment, endpoint, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-deployment

I wanted to load test a deployed model endpoint and add it to an MLOps framework, so that new deployed models can go through load testing. I tried Azure load testing resource for web app but I think it is just for static content. Also, I saw a python package - locust which seems promising. Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

The load test is not only for the static content, and it will be available for the dynamic content and there is a clause in this. The HTTP URL must be consisting of”**[http://appname.azurewebsites.net/login**”](http://appname.azurewebsites.net/login**%E2%80%9D) extension (**azurewebsites.com**). It must be assigned to the webpage which is having the user operations and then the load test can be done without using “**locust**” package. Checkout the flow mentioned below for the same requirement.

**Create a prediction model using Automated ML. In this case, created one classification model and generated URL required.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]